# How too loop arrays using cython?

Tags: python, arrays, cython, numpy-ndarray, numba

I was trying to iterate arrays using different options. However all of them took a lot of processing time. How can I use do array iteration in Cython?

```
#Assign the crop specific irrigated area of each array for each month according to the crop calander
#Maize
arr_5=maz_st_1
#repaeat it for every twelve month
arr5_re=np.repeat(arr_5, 12)
maz_itr=arr5_re.flatten()
maz_itr=arr5_re.tolist()
k=df_dist.Planting_month[5]
l=df_dist.Maturity_month[5]
for i in range (len(maz_itr)):
     for j in range(min(k,l), max(k,l)+1):
          for n in range (len(df_area.Maize)):
           # Assign the grid cell value for each growing month of maize
              df_area.loc[n,"Maize"]=maz_itr[i]
```

My goal is to assign the growing area for each grid cell for each crop. In this case I would like to distribute the area of maize for each grid cell under the growing season condition (when the month is between the planting and maturity date of the crop).

Answer (score 0):

```
def axis_to_axeslist(axis, ndim): if axis is None: 
return [-1] * ndim else: if type(axis) is not tuple: 
axis = (axis,) axeslist = [1] * ndim for i in 
axis: axeslist[i] = -1 ax = 0 for i in range(ndim): 
if axeslist[i] != -1: axeslist[i] = ax 

ax += 1 return axeslist def sum_squares_py(arr, axis=None, out=None): axeslist = axis_to_axeslist(axis, arr.ndim) it = np.nditer([arr, out], flags=['reduce_ok', 'buffered', 'delay_bufalloc'], op_flags=[['readonly'], ['readwrite', 'allocate']], 

op_axes=[None, axeslist], op_dtypes=['float64', 'float64']) with it: it.operands[1][...] = 0 it.reset() for x, y in it: y[...] += x*x return it.operands[1] 
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3) sum_squares_py(a) array(55.) sum_squares_py(a, axis=-1) array([ 5., 50.])
```

---

Comment: As written, this is not syntactically legal Python. Please fix the indentation, and provide some explanation of *why* you made changes, and what the benefit provided is (code-only answers are not nearly as helpful for learning lessons for the future).